# What are the differences between Next.js 13 server components and client components?

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to understand the differences between Next.js 13 server components and client components, and I have a few questions:

1. If the server component doesn't have the ability to access hooks, what is the benefit of using it, and how can users interact with it?(state, reactivity)
2. Are both client components and server components SEO-friendly, or is one better for SEO than the other?
3. Can we hide API endpoints with client components like we can with server components?

A sample situation:
`app/abc/page.tsx`

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Error:

```
"useState" is not allowed in Server Components.ts(71001)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75325716/difference-between-next-12-client-side-routing-and-next-13-server-centric-routin/75497017#75497017

Comment: My question was not how can I use useState or hooks with next 13? instead my question was what is the benifit if developer can not use useStete, etc hooks with a server component? where the use case? just like static html, css, vanilla js website? what is the benifit of using nextjs then? actually these were my questions. May be I dont' know but someone knows.

Answer (score 0):

1. All Next components have ability to access hooks. But for example useEffect will be executed only in client side.
2. Server component better for SEO. Because for search engines SSR page looks like static HTML already generated on server.
3. Hide like SSR - no. Because  components rendered in server side and all method required for render called on server. But user requests will be on client side and with SSR and with CSR. But Next offers a built-in proxy function

Yes, with `app` dir exists some problems.
[image]

This approach allows you to make SSR component without getServerSide props and with some others new features. But this is beta and if for you it creates some problem, dont use `app` dir, use `getServerSideProps`

Comment: "1. All Next components have ability to access hooks. But for example useEffect will be executed only in client side." - are you sure with your answer?

Comment: Yes. I've been working with next about 2 years. 'server component doesn't have the ability to access hooks' is wrong. It depends on hook realization. And this is not a problem

Comment: But, I get error when I use `useState` or any built in hooks, and I need to shift `use client` directive forcefully to resolve the error, but using that directive make it client component! [next-13 reference](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#convention)

Comment: see my question I have added a sample. if I add `"use client";` it works fine, but then its not a server component.

Comment: oh, this is a complex issue) Yes, `use client` make component client rendered. With next 13 and app dir feature you have to choose way to manage states and components with different type of render. https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/understanding-server-components-in-react-18-and-next-js-13/. But this feature added recently and it is beta. For this reason, right now I am not introducing an app dir into my projects. If you needs stable solution, use getServerSideProps. Using beta it is always requires some research

Comment: I am familiar with previous versions. Do you mean this behave is not intentional? future updates it will be fixed?

Comment: Yes, i think so. You can read official docs to get more understanding https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#rendering-third-party-context-providers-in-server-components
And for example I use effector in my project and useState I use not often. And seems like it will work. But i didnt try)

Comment: I believe I have read somewhere in next-13 official docs, mentioned `useState` or hooks can not be used with server components. Also, I believe its intentional until now.

Comment: maybe in next updates it will be changed to some different approach. I think developers of next are looking for an easiest way to make app, without getServer SideProps, without any other manipulations

Comment: Yes you can see there clearly written useState, etc. can not use with server component, My question was not how can I use useState or hooks with next 13? instead my question was what is the benifit if developer can not use useStete, etc hooks with a server component? where the use case? just like static html, css, vanilla js website? what is the benifit of using nextjs then? actually these were my questions. May be I dont' know but someone knows.

Comment: Regarding nextjs-13, I'm curious about the meaning of these ❌ symbols. Will these features be removed in the upcoming version or added later? If they will be added later, why did they use an ❌ instead of a progress indicator to show that it's a work in progress? It seems to me that the ❌ symbol indicates that these features will remain closed for next.js 13. Even eventListeners are ❌! so just to render raw json data modified with html, css!

Comment: Noticed that the client component for data fetching has an attention ⚠️ symbol. This suggests that the data fetching feature for client components is still being developed, and there is no ❌ symbol for that.