# NextJs 13 server-centric vs client-side routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js

What are the differences between server-centric and client-side routing in Next.js 13 or higher, and how do they impact web application development?

How does that affect data fetching?

I have searched the internet but could not find answers clear enough...

Comment: This post answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75325716/difference-between-next-12-client-side-routing-and-next-13-server-centric-routin